# What is the exact size of the status bar at top of the iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried to add a `UITableView` programmatically to my view, but setting its parameters as follows doesn't work (the last cell is cropped).

```
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

I tried to replace the height by 460, which works pretty well. But I want to know the exact size of this bar :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: don't hard-code the size of screen features! you will be screwed later. `UIViewController` should properly size your views for you--make sure you set up your auto resizing or springs & struts properly.

Comment: i.e. the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: also, it's called the "status bar"

Comment: So if I don't hard-code my screen size, how can I set it automatically to fit my `UIViewController` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You should never hardcode the exact value of the height at any point in your code.

As long as you use default UI components (`UINavigationController` / `UITableView` / `UICollectionView` / etc.) you usually don't need to worry about the status bar height at all. These ViewControllers should layout correctly on any device and any orientation.

If you do have custom layout needs, you should refer to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` on `UIView`, instead of hardcoding a height:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide?language=objc

---

But to make this answer complete - the size of the status bar is different on different devices and different orientations:

- Most devices **up to the iPhone X** have a 20pt height in portrait & landscape.
  (20px, 40px, 60px in @1x, @2x, @3x)
- On **iPhone X** in portrait it's 44pt (so 44px, 88px, 132px accordingly).
  In landscape the height is different though.

Comment: Actually, it's 20px on non-retina or 40px on retina... either way, it's 20 pts, but +1, I agree "you shouldn't need this value in your code."

Comment: I just gave it a try by creating a new single view application, then I added a UITableView in my ViewController that I add with `[self.view addSubview:table];`, that's probably because of it. Is it something wrong with that way of doing?

Comment: Aww, the good pre-iPhoneX times. How I thought life couldn't get worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent view controller will resize it's view to the right size. You can

- make your view controller load a subclass of UIView and override `-layoutSubviews`
- insert your subview with the proper starting size (`[[ MyViewClass alloc ] initWithFrame:superview.bounds]`) and the proper autoresizing mask. It's important when using autoresizing struts & springs that you give your view the proper size to start with.

BTW--another problem with hard coding the status bar height: it's sometimes double-height. (when the user is recording audio, making a phone call, using internet tethering, using navigation, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to Rob's question in the comments to the original question:

> So if I don't hard-code my screen size, how can I set it automatically to fit my UIViewController?

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // all other table setup
    table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}
```

This assumes you want the table view to fill the view controller's view. Adjust as needed.

This will ensure the table view's size changes as the view controller's view size changes. This covers rotations, in-call status bars, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and the explanations, very clear :)

Answer (score 1):

You should't use set pixel dimensions to size something to the screen. use you view's frame. i.e.

```
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Anyway. It's 20 points. 20px non retina. 40px retina.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for iPhone X**

Previously all iPhone devices have a status bar height of 20pt. But on iPhone X, it's 44pt. So be careful when implementing your UI.